# How can I remove the title "leave a reply" in the comment box in twentyeleven?

Tags: functions, comments

I would like to remove "leave a reply" in the comment form in twenty eleven. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can filter the default `comment_form` arguments (which is what's causing the "leave a reply").

Just drop this in `functions.php` or in a plugin file.  It would probably be better to put it in a plugin and keep your twenty eleven theme unedited (read: easily updated).

```
<?php
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'wpse33039_form_defaults' );
function wpse33039_form_defaults( $defaults )
{
    $defaults['title_reply'] = '';
    return $defaults;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

edit comments.php, 
and find:
`comment_form()`;

edit to:
`comment_form(array('title_reply'=>''))`